# QBFC (Quickbook 2012 Prod) Refunding Credit Memo using SDK

Tags: api, qbfc

Is there a way via the QuickBooks SDK (QBFC) to import a Check refund w/o also creating a corresponding Credit Memo and linking the CC/Check refund to the Credit Memo Txn ?

The QB UI allows opening up Credit Memo and then using "Use Credit to" -> "Give Refund" option. I am trying the achieve the same using the QB SDK QBFC API.

Regards,
Jenis

Answer (score 0):

The QB UI process is creating a credit memo and linking the CC/Check refund to the Credit Memo transaction, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve if you don't want to create the credit memo.

A credit memo in QuickBooks will reduce Accounts Receivable and (typically) reduce an Income account. The CC/Check refund will increase Accounts Receivable and reduce the bank or cc account.

If you don't want to create a credit memo, then you would simply create a check or cc transaction that offset the Income account that would normally be on the credit memo.